# Need .bat that will make folder based on filename

Tags: batch, batch-file

I need .bat that will make folders based on filenames and put files inside. I have names formatted like this:

```
string1 - string2 - string3 - string2 - string3_number.jpg
```

I find out command that will take 3 first strings as i needed, but cant make it work further. When i try to put this command into bat it makes only folder called "--".

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (set string1=%%a&set string2=%%b&set string3=%%c
md "%string1%-%string2%-%string3%")
```

putting @echo off and setlocal before this in .bat dont work
can someone help make it right so it will make folders based on names and put files in.
I read these posts but still can't even make folders:

- [Batch Create a Folder Based on Filename, and Move Multiple Related Files to The Created Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921039/batch-create-a-folder-based-on-filename-and-move-multiple-related-files-to-the)
- [Need a script to create folders based on file names, and auto move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441317/need-a-script-to-create-folders-based-on-file-names-and-auto-move-files)
- [Batch create folders based on part of file name and move files into that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992530/batch-create-folders-based-on-part-of-file-name-and-move-files-into-that-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [delayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is required when setting **and** using a var in a (code block) it doesn't work.

But as you don't change the vars that isn't needed at all.

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (
  set "Folder=%%a-%%b-%%c"
  Rem to remove the trailing space from the Folder
  set "Folder=!Folder:~0,-1!"
  If not exist "!Folder!\" MD "!Folder!"
)
```

To also move files that is the wrong approach, you should then 1st iterate the files and 2nd split them as above.

Comment: Well done @LotPings. Introduced in 1999... I never knew about Delayed Expansion.